# Problem with repository access from a docker container on a gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**tl;dr**

What is the intended way, the philosophy, to work with a gitlab runner with docker support and finished containers and source code from repositories? How can I mount a source code repository into a container?

---

We are currently converting our gitlab runner (native) to gitlab runner with docker support. These work differently in terms of their philosophy and I still have problems to understand how we can use them for our purposes.
Even though the question is a bit broad, I try to limit it to a more concrete use case.

Let us assume that we want to do a code analysis in a programming project (e.g. Java or C++), which should be done regularly after a push into the develop branch.

Stage 1: Build a Container
For this purpose I create a docker file and assemble all required applications and libraries there. I push this container into our registry, so that it can be used again and again. Only if I modify the dockerfile, it should be rebuilt.

Stage 2: Validate the SourceCode
In this step, the Docker container is to be pulled and the source code is to be analyzed. Here comes my problem: How does a container get the source code from a repository?

I already tried to include the source code folder using the docker call via `-v`, but it doesn't seem to work. I get error messages that `-v` is not a executable program. So I guess that this possibility is not intended.

Another possibility would be to integrate the source code when building the container, but I don't think that would be useful. Another possibility would be to include a path via the `config.toml`, analog to `-v`, but even that does not seem to be the right solution to me. I can only get to the config file via `ssh`.

Another solution would be to check out the source code in the running container via git... also not pretty.

To cut a long story short: What is the intended way, the philosophy, to work with finished containers and source code from repositories?

---

We're using a gitlab runner together with the shell executor.

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
  CI_REGISTRY: ***
  CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: ***/test
  CI_REGISTRY_USER: ***
  CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ***


stages:
- build
- test

before_script:
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY

build_container:
  stage: build
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
  tags:
    - docker
  before_script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest 
  script:
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
  after_script:
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

validate:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE /script/to/validate/code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem by reading the `Docker` [manual](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) again. The execution error of `-v` resides from putting the parameter in the wrong place. The example below shows the right way to use it.

explanation:

- `--rm` - causes Docker to automatically remove the container when it exits
- `-v` - causes Docker to mount the repository/project `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` in `/mnt` of the container

code snippet:

```
validate:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker run --rm -v $CI_PROJECT_DIR:/mnt $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE /bin/ash -c "/some/command /mnt/sourcecode/"
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the confusion is stemming from mushing together two things that are meant to be separate.

A Docker image should be built and published in its own project if you are wanting to reuse it. Some builds take a while, so you can save time by using an already built image.

Once you have an image ready to be pulled down, you can move on to using the image for whatever you want.

You call the image down in the gitlab-ci.yml file and then its has access to the repository of the project the pipeline is being ran in.

In the gitlab-ci.yml you use the 'image' tag to specify what docker image you would like to use. You can specify an image for a single job.

```yml
image: python

python job:
  script: python hello-world.py

java job:
  image: golang
  script: go run hello-world.go
```

Comment: You describe exactly the way I implemented it, as you can see in my code snippet. The significant difference is the executor. You describe the behaviour of the `docker executor` as it is used in the `Docker-in-Docker`-scenario. But we are using a standard `shell executor` that works different. With this executor you don't have the repo already mounted and `image:` is not availabe.
see also https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html